# Problems with model.destroy()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Whenever I do a model.destroy() with Backbone, it tries to do a DELETE request on the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/item/?format=json
```

Since I am doing a destroy on a model, I would expect that the ID of the model should be passed, so the URL to do a DELETE request on would be this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/item/8/?format=json
```

where the ID is specified. Because of the lack of ID, and my use of tastypie, all items get deleted. How do I make it so that the URL contains the ID of the item that I wish to delete?

Comment: Are you overriding the `url` method on the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your model looks something like this:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/api/v1/item/?format=json',
    // ...
});
```

The `url` for a model is supposed to be a function but, since it [ends up going through](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1326) the internal [`getValue`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1422) function, a string will also "work"; if you check the source I linked to, you'll see why a string for `url` would give you the results you're seeing.

The solution is to use a function for [`url`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url) as you're supposed to:

> **url** `model.url()`
>
> Returns the relative URL where the model's resource would be located on the server. If your models are located somewhere else, override this method with the correct logic. Generates URLs of the form: `"/[collection.url]/[id]"`, falling back to `"/[urlRoot]/id"` if the model is not part of a collection.

You'd probably want something like this:

```
url: function() {
    if(this.isNew())
        return '/api/v1/item/?format=json';
    return '/api/v1/item/' + encodeURIComponent(this.id) + '/?format=json';
}
```

or this:

```
url: function() {
    if(this.isNew())
        return '/api/v1/item/?format=json';
    return '/api/v1/item/' + encodeURIComponent(this.get('id')) + '/?format=json';
}
```

Comment: encodeURLComponent returns a URL that looks like http://localhost:8000/api/v1/item//api/v1/item/29//?format=json. How would I get just the ID?

Comment: @egidra: That doesn't make sense, what do your `id`s look like? Are they numbers or strings like `'/api/v1/item/29/'`?

Comment: Sorry, they look like what you just typed: '/api/v1/item/29/'. When the URL returns it looks like 'localhost:8000/api/v1/item//api/v1/item/29//?format=json'. My ids look like '/api/v1/item/29/'.

Comment: @egidra: That's a funny looking ID you have there, you might want to fix it be just the number. In the mean time, `return this.id + '?format=json'` should work, you'd want to keep the "is new" branch as-is though.

Comment: Do you know what might be the cause for the id to look that? Does it have something to do with my API? I am using Tastypie. When I fetch a list of objects, each object has a JSON with an attribute of resource_uri. This matches 'this.id'

Comment: I don't know anything about Tastypie (except the kind I bake of course), you could use [`parse`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) to clean them up if necessary. Does Tastypie include just a plain `id` in the JSON?

Comment: For a simple fix, I am using return '/api/v1/item/' + this.get("id") + '/?format=json';

Comment: I should have thought of that.